# Is it possible for an iOS app to communicate with Google Authenticator?

Tags: ios, security, cordova, ios7, google-authenticator

I have an API that needs to register once with a HOTP/TOTP code before it is given a longer term session token.

Is there any way (in theory) that an iOS app can "call" a modified version of Google Authenticator that would allow for the one time exchange of the HOTP / TOTP code?

I'm assuming that the modified version of Google Authenticator would issue a prompt like

> "Are you sure you want to send a code for XXX to YYY?"

Is there any way this scenario could be possible?  Lacking this, I'll have to direct the user to multitask between apps, a feature that my consumers don't know how do to on iOS.  (double clicking the button at the bottom of the phone or iPad eludes them)

Some thoughts that make me think this is possible:

- I have seen weblinks in Safari open up an app on the device, or websites that open the app instead of the the .mobile version when installed (Foursquare, Facebook, etc)
- An app can open a website in Safari or Chrome

Taking these thoughts together, I could add a URL parameter containing the HOTP code, and "bounce it back" over HTTPS, but I'd like a more local solution

---

Note to closer(s): I'm asking this on Security.SE because I would think that people here might know the most about iOS sandboxing since the concepts and skills needed here might be conceptually similar to [ASLR and DEP which have 74+ questions on the site](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=dep).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, simply by using the shared `UIApplication` object and the `openURL` method. The scheme is detailed in the [KeyUriFormat page](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/wiki/KeyUriFormat) of the Google Authenticator wiki.

The code should look something like this:

```
NSString *issuer = @"Example";
NSString *accountname = @"alice@google.com";
NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",issuer,accountname];
NSString *secret = @"JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP";
NSString *algorithm = @"SHA1";
NSString *digits = @"6";
NSString *period = @"30";

NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"otpauth://totp/%@?secret=%@&issuer=%@&algorithm=%@&digits=%@&period=%@",label,secret,issuer,algorithm,digits,period];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPath];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

However, at the moment there seems to be [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/issues/detail?id=337) which crashes the current version of the iOS app (I've tested it).

:(

Alternatively, you could incorporate your own implementation of TOTP in your app. It's not too complicated, I've actually put together a simple example [here](https://github.com/yazid/iOS-TOTP).

Comment: Hmm, this seems to add a new TOTP entry into Google Authenticator,  my goal is to have app-app communication

Comment: @makerofthings7: Not that I'm aware of. Most likely route for you seems to be to incorporate the TOTP algorithm within your app. Since it's an open spec you'll get the same results of the Google Authenticator app anyway.